# Pause CSS Animation For n Seconds

Tags: css, web, css-animations

I animated a simple automatic image slider, but the first and last images take longer, while the middle images are quite fast.

How can I even the times and pause each image for let's say 6 seconds and then continue. I have tried the `animation-play-state:paused;`, but I am not sure how to add time.

Here is some of the code I have:

```
    .image-container {
      -webkit-animation-name: autoplay;
      animation-name: autoplay;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
      animation-duration: 20s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

     @-webkit-keyframes 
  autoplay {  
    0% {
   left: 0px;
  }
  
    25% {
   left: -1920px;
  }
    
    50% {
   left: -3840px;
  }
  
    100% {
   left: -5760px;
  }
}

@keyframes 
autoplay {  
  0% {
 left: 0px;
}

  25% {
 left: -1920px;
}
  
  50% {
 left: -3840px;
}

  100% {
 left: -5760px;
}
}
```

Comment: I guess the only thing you can do is to play with the percentages... From what you posted, we just don't know how many images are inside `.image-container`... CSS doesn't know either.

Comment: There are 4 images inside. Isn't there anyway to pause the animation for 5 seconds when it reaches a certain percentage?

Comment: I don't think so. But you know the ratio between the 4 images. So you can play with the percentages. Like having the 4 `%` knots of the CSS more like 0 - 35 - 65 - 100...

Comment: ELSE... And if the image are not to be always the same. I would look for an animation libray like [Greensock](https://greensock.com/docs/)... But that may be a huge step.

Comment: Good resource. Definitely gonna check that out when I feel more confident with the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by playing with the keyframes like **Louys Patrice Bessette** suggested:

```
@keyframes 
autoplay {  
  0%,15% {
 left: 0px;
}
  25%,40% {
 left: -1920px;
}
  50%,65% {
 left: -3840px;
}
  100% {
 left: -5760px;
}
```

Comment: There you go! ;)